# How to handle a huge amount of requests to Write on a single file?

Tags: php, file, logging

Well, in a project I have to log all actions of users, inclusive: db queries, requests to services,... in a logfile ( NOT database ). There's a class for this which creates logs. despite all actions comes to `createLog` method ( in `logClass` ), most of them can't be logged, because of limitations of Readng and writing in files.

Is there any way to handle this, something like a queue implementation or what ever? What is the best way to handle such these things?

PS: I've tried flock() and ...

Thanks.

Comment: locks() only apply to the current php process, other processes can modify or delete a locked file

Comment: @user1844933 Locks are advisory, but this looks like a context where it should work because all processes would be issuing locks the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about PHP but in general if you are generating a lot of logs you should not write them to file directly (specially if writing concurrently from multiple processes/threads).

As an alternative you could use syslog. Most programming languages can log to syslog instead of a file. The syslog program (for example https://syslog-ng.org/) can output your logs into a single (or multiple based on the config you provide) file.